# Using Firebase and AWS Amplify as back end for one Android app

Tags: android, firebase, backend, aws-amplify

Firebase has some great features compared to AWS. But it is not a good option for big Data transaction apps like e-commerce.

And also firebase data transfer cost is also a bit higher than AWS.

There are so many articles on the web which shows difference between these two services. But no one says developers can use both services in one Android app.

I need some features of Firebase and some features of AWS.
So, Can I use both Firebase and AWS Amplify as a back end for single Android app?

Comment: I do require the same answer. In my case, I need more data transfer than storing files. but firebase data transfer cost is too much for me. In my opinion, firebase is not a suitable option for apps like social media or e-commerce apps, I mean firebase data transfer (bandwidth).